# create array of keys from an object Android

Tags: android, arrays

I'm wanting to create an array of all keys within an object does anyone know how to do this in Android? in iOS I have done this

```
NSDictionary *variablesDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
// ^^ full of variables and keys...

NSString *finalString = @"";
if(variablesDictionary != nil){
    NSArray *keysArray = [variablesDictionary allKeys];
    for(NSString *singleKey in keysArray) {
        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", singleKey, [variablesDictionary objectForKey:singleKey]]];
    }
}

//final string will = '&key=variable&key=variable&key=variable&key=variable' etc...
```

heres what i have tried so far. heres my global actions

```
 public final static void startAPICallRequest(Context activityContext, String request, String apiLocation, Object postVarsObj, Object getVarsObj){

            long unixTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

            if(getVarsObj != null){

                Array keysArray = getVarsObj.keySet().toArray();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String key : getVarsObj.keySet()) {
                    sb.append("&");
                    sb.append(key);
                    sb.append("=");
                    sb.append(getVarsObj.get(key).toString());
                }

                final String will = sb.toString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What are the keys? How does your object look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
// for Map<String, Object>
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    sb.append("&");
    sb.append(key);
    sb.append("=");
    sb.append(map.get(key).toString());
}

final String will = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This brings up an error asking me to add a cast to 'map' or 'variablesDictionary' in my case. Can you advise?

Comment: What type do you use for the dictionary?

Comment: If you use the Object type, you shouldn't be able to access the field in the variable (unless you try with reflection). You should probably use a map or an interface. How to you call that method? And what is the instance type of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

If using a map, you'll want to take a look at the keySet() functionality. [Here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Createanarraycontainingthekeysinamap.htm)